# Grouping of cells not working properly in excel

Tags: excel, grouping

I have the following data in the excel sheet-
[image]

I want to group the cells by `Patient ID`. When I try to group, it creates only one group for all rows and only one "minus" sign for all rows. How to group properly for all rows by `Patient ID`

Comment: What to you mean by “group by”. What is the expected result?

Comment: Grouing by means - when I click minus sign for a group, all the values of same "Patient ID" should be minimized

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with your data as it is now. You need an extra row between the different groups for it to work, otherwise you end up with a single group for all rows.

One possible easy-to-do solution is to use Subtotal (the icon is to the right of the Group button in the UI), which will insert a new row for you with, well, subtotals. You can set it to "count Patient ID" for instance.

[image]

The downside of this solution is that the subtotals row (or any row in between the groups, even if you leave an empty row) will not hide when contracting the groups.

- Rows grouped, separated with an empty row:

[image]

- Rows grouped using Subtotal:

[image]